# Domain doesn't work in browser but works on other devices

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

I registered a domain like example.com and was waiting for it to start resolving.

My PC browser (Chrome) showed the "This site can’t be reached" page, so I thought the domain was still propagating. However, when I tried the domain on my phone, it worked.

The phone and PC were connected to the same router, so they were getting internet from the same source (although the phone might have used cellular data.)

- Why was the domain not resolving on my PC browser when it resolved on my phone?
- After a while, the PC browser did start successfully resolving. Is there a way to speed this process up?
- How can I discern if the domain isn't resolving due to the browser/OS? (So it might work on a different device.)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a caching issue. Maybe your PC was using your router as a dns server and it cached that example.com didnt resolve. Or maybe your own PC cached it. I'm thinking your cell phone probably used another dns server. On your PC, you could've tried to speed it up with `ipconfig /flushdns` to force it to query the dns again and hopefully get an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Chrome caching the DNS. To fix:

- `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and click "Clear host cache."
- `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` and click "Close idle sockets," "Flush socket pools."

Source: https://superuser.com/q/203674/4390